# AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'max_sr'

Tags: python

I am getting

```py
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'max_sr'
```

in the following code

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(15,2))
librosa.display.waveshow(y=y, sr=sr, max_sr=1000, alpha=0.25, color='blue')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would help us to figure out the issue.

Comment: [`librosa.display.waveshow`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.display.waveshow.html) does not accept `max_sr` argument. May be you wanted to use `max_points`?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help,I solved the error.